# Qt Creator не работают автоподсказки автодополнения(Не Qt приложение)

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Проблема в том что сами автоподсказки работают, но не полностью.Не видит некоторые функции, хотя компиляция проходит успешно.Функции которые видны выделены жирным (Смотреть фото). И на Линуксе нет некоторых функций которые есть в Винде (тот же самый **itoa**).Подскажите как исправить.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Переустанавливал и на Винде и на Линюхе - не помогло.

Comment: Как исправить? подключить заголовочные файлы, где определены используемые символы напрямую. Для `ios::*` `#include <ios>`, Для `itoa` - `#include <cstdlib>`... И тд

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.С ios проблем нет. Но попробовал - результат нулевой.То что нет Itoa меня не очень раздражает. Но то что среда не видит функций, а в компиляторе они есть и програма нормально компилируется раздражает до беcконечности.

Comment: @ВіталійБілий у тебя Qt Creator "битый"  у тебя верхняя строка вся с ошибками.

Comment: @timob256 Где именно?Qt Creator переведен на украинский, бага сохраняется на разных машинах с разными ОС и языками